# Error in seq.default(1, length(tokens), 5000) : wrong sign in 'by' argument in R

Tags: r, text, sequence

I am trying to create a document term matrix (`dtm`), but am faced with the below error.

```
dtm <- CreateDtm(tokens$text, 
                 stopword_vec = c(stopwords::stopwords("en")),
                 doc_names = tokens$ID, 
                 ngram_window = c(1, 2),lower = TRUE, remove_punctuation = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)
```

Error:

> Error in seq.default(1, length(tokens), 5000) : wrong sign in 'by' argument

`dput(head(tokens))` gives the following:

```
structure(list(Index = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Paper = c("9201001", 
"9201002", "9201003", "9201004", "9201005", "9201006"), `1` = c("combinatorics", 
"inomogeneous", "intersection", "heterotic", "ward", "symmetries"
), `2` = c("modular", "quantum", "theory", "green", "identities", 
"massless"), `3` = c("ii", "symmetries", "integrable", "schwarz", 
"dimensional", "field"), `4` = c("", "phonons", "hierarchies", 
"superstring", "string", "theories"), `5` = c("", "", "topological", 
"super", "theory", ""), `6` = c("", "", "field", "worldsheet", 
"", ""), `7` = c("", "", "theory", "", "", ""), `8` = c("", "", 
"", "", "", ""), `9` = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), `10` = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), `11` = c("", "", "", "", "", ""), `12` = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    Paper = c("9201001", "9201002", "9201003", "9201004", "9201005", 
    "9201006"), .rows = list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = FALSE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Wonder what went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this because you have no column called `text` in your data frame:

```
length(tokens$text)
#> [1] 0
#> Warning message:
#> Unknown or uninitialised column: `text`.
```

This means when, as part of its algorithm, `CreatDtm` tries to create a sequence based on the number of tokens, it is calling:

```
seq(1, 0, 5000)
#> Error in seq.default(1, 0, 5000) : wrong sign in 'by' argument
```

Your columns in the example are all numbered and would have to be referred to using back-ticks like this:

```
tokens$`1`
```

However, for `CreateDtm` you would want to pass the whole data frame rather than just one column:

```r
CreateDtm(tokens)
#> 14 x 25 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
#>    [[ suppressing 25 column names ‘combinatorics’, ‘dimensional’, ‘green’ ... ]]
#>                                                        
#> Index . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> Paper . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> 1     1 . . 1 . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 .
#> 2     . . 1 . . 1 . . . . 1 1 . 1 . . . . . . . . . . 1
#> 3     . 1 . . . . 1 . 1 . . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 1 .
#> 4     . . . . 1 . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . 1 1 . . . . . .
#> 5     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 . . 1 . . . . 1
#> 6     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1 1 . .
#> 7     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 1
#> 8     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> 9     . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> 10    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> 11    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
#> 12    . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
```

Obviously, this is just the result for the head of your data frame rather than the whole thing.

Comment: Thank you. But when I pass the whole dataframe (i.e. `tokens` instead of `tokens$name`), I get this error: `Error in dimnamesGets(x, value) : 
  invalid dimnames given for “dgCMatrix” object`

Comment: @Grace have you also removed `doc_names = tokens$ID` from your call, since this doesn't exist either?

Comment: Sorry, it should be `tokens$Paper` - however, this doesn't work too.

Comment: @Grace do you get the same error if you just do `CreateDtm(tokens)`?

Comment: There is no error if using `CreateDtm(tokens)`. Only error if using `tokens$Paper` for the docnames.

Comment: @Grace the input seems a bit weird here. You are supposed to pass the documents in to `CreateDtm` as a character vector rather than as a data frame of tokens. Do you have the original texts? You could try just passing them